# .vimrc causes error only inside virtualenv

Tags: vim, python-venv

I had meant to use VIM editor for developing within venv that I setup using a University machine with command to load python36 from the server I believe. (as I were to use `scl`) Outside of this particular venv, I have no problem invoking `vi` command to edit files, but I do inside the venv.

```
(venv) [----]UUN: vi ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /afs/inf.ed.ac.uk/user/s18/sUUN/.vimrc:
line   11:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
line   13:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8'
line   14:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
line   15:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'Royal-Colorschemes'
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'powerline/powerline'
line   22:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'godlygeek/tabular'
```

I do not understand why. Can someone enlighten.. Following is my `~/.vimrc` not on the venv.

```
1 set nocompatible
2 filetype off
3 
4 " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
5 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
6 call vundle#begin()
7 " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
8 "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
9 
10 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
11 Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
12 "place plugin here
13 Plugin 'https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8'
14 Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
15 Plugin 'Royal-Colorschemes'
16 Plugin 'powerline/powerline'
17 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
18 call vundle#end()            " required
19 
20 filetype plugin indent on
21 
22 Bundle 'godlygeek/tabular'
23 set fileencodings=utf-8
24 set encoding=utf-8
25 
26 syntax on
27 
28 set tabstop=8
29 set expandtab
30 set shiftwidth=4
31 set softtabstop=4
32 
33 set nu
34 set paste
35 
36 set autoindent
37 set cindent
38 
39 set laststatus=2
40 set modeline
41 set background=dark
42 
43 " Key Map "
44 nmap nerd :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Using VIM worked!
Thank you. (but why does it not work for `vi`?)

Comment: Have you updated the run time path in your /afs/inf.ed.ac.uk/user/s18/s1885807/.vimrc to include: `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`

Comment: @gregory OP says working fine outside venv. My question is why invoking as vi and not as vim?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: Is `$HOME` different inside/outside the virtualenv? It looks like you're missing the `~/.vim` directory... Also, post your `.vimrc` or snippets of it, you might be missing something in your Vundle setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work in vi, because you've haven't `set compatible`. Instead, you've explicitly set in your .vimrc the non compatible mode: `set nocompatible`.  You can try setting the compatible mode on, but I doubt if any of these plugins will work -- but I haven't personally tested this point. Rather, I keep to the rule of thumb: use vim when using plugins written for vim.